# Received the following error while running a hive query. What could be the possible reasons for it?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop-partitioning

> java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED:
>   Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed,
>   vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1538324912862_7122_1_00,
>   diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1538324912862_7122_1_00_000083,
>   diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running
>   task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before
>   newline: 2147483648

Comment: Can you please add your query and some more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the files in your table does not have the newline record delimiter or somehow does not conform with table schema (check also FIELDS TERMINATED BY, maybe it specified wrong in table DDL).

You can check job tracker logs to find file name processed.

Exception `java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline: 2147483648` - this is because the maximum size a string can have is: `2^31-1 = 2147483647`